# Multi-homed network?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a network with a layout like this:

```
*******           ******            *******            ******
* SW1 * --------- * R1 * ---------- * SW2 * ---------- * R2 *
*******           ******            *******            ******
                     |                                    |
                     |                                    |
                 ********                             ********
                 * ISP1 *                             * ISP2 *
                 ********                             ********
```

**SW1** = Switch with multiple clients connected.
**R1** = Primary router on the network. This router handles DHCP.
**ISP1** = Primary Internet uplink. All clients should use this by default.
**SW2** = Switch with multiple clients connected.
**R2** = Secondary router on the network.
**ISP2** = Secondary Internet uplink. Clients should use this for specific traffic and if **ISP1** fails.

By default all clients have **R1** as default gateway, and connects to Internet through **ISP1**.

*However, all traffic with destination port 995 or 465 should go to **ISP2**, and if **ISP1** goes down, all Internet traffic on the network should go to **ISP2**.*

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. What would be the correct strategy to do this?

**R1** and **R2** are regular computers with multiple network cards and Debian installed.

Comment: Do your routers support policy-based routing?

Comment: The routers are regular Linux computers, so I did some research and found out about a collection of utilities called `iproute2`. These utilites should enable one to configure policy-based routing, so the answer to you question is yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the correct strategy would be:

- Use `iptables --mark` to add tags to the special packages you have (e.g. `iptable -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 995 -j MARK --set-mark 1`)
- Use this mark to set a special route via **R2** (see http://nerdboys.com/2006/05/05/conning-the-mark-multiwan-connections-using-iptables-mark-connmark-and-iproute2/ or http://blog.khax.net/2009/11/28/multi-gateway-routing-with-iptables-and-iproute2/)
- Route the other packets via **R1**, but give them also **R2** with a different weight/prio.

The proper term for searching is "multihomed routing". I don't have a good howto at hand right now.